# getting data from a website - download link with adjustable date range

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

Really new to web scraping, sorry to leave such an open question. In a way I want to know about feasibility as much as how to do it.

I only really use python (which may be a bit of a setback for webscraping in general?)

Annoyingly this site only lets you download 1 month at a time, which you need to manually define with the date range, and you can only get one type of data at a time as well. This time I will just do it manually, but in the future if I knew a bit more about web scraping I'm sure there would be a neater way to go about it.

Any tips on where to start?

https://www.regelleistung.net/ext/data/

Answer (score 2):

Using selenium is one option. I am using python 2.7. Be careful configuring the webdriver, sometimes can be a little bit hard. You could improve it to select just the months that you need download.This example download from January to December.[image: Code working]

```
import os
import sys
import time
import calendar
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

# Open the website using webdriver Chrome  
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
try:
    browser.get('https://www.regelleistung.net/ext/data/')
except:
    print '\n #### No se puede abrir la pagina, comprueba tu coneccion a internet #### \n'

# Set as check Herunterladen check botton 
browser.find_element_by_id('form-download').click()

list_years = ['2017', '2018']

for year in list_years:

    for month in range(1, 12): # From January to December 

        last_day = calendar.monthrange(int(year), int(month))[1] # Last day of a month

        start_date = '01' + '.' + str(month) + '.' + str(year)
        end_date = str(last_day) + '.' + str(month) + '.' + str(year)

        legend = ' \nRange ' + start_date + ' to ' + end_date + '\n'
        print legend

        # Fill the date range
        browser.find_element_by_id('form-from-date').clear()
        time.sleep(1)
        browser.find_element_by_id('form-from-date').send_keys(start_date)

        browser.find_element_by_id('form-to-date').clear()
        time.sleep(1)
        browser.find_element_by_id('form-to-date').send_keys(end_date)

        # Search each UNB option and then save them into a list
        unb = browser.find_element_by_id('form-tso') 
        unb_options = unb.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')

        unb_list = list()
        for unbOption in unb_options:
            text_unb = unbOption.text
            unb_list.append(text_unb)

        # Download each element on UNB button options 
        for unb_list_element in unb_list:

            time.sleep(1)
            select_unb = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('form-tso')) 
            select_unb.select_by_visible_text(unb_list_element)

            # Search each Datentyp option and then save them into a list
            datentyp = browser.find_element_by_id('form-type')
            datentyp_options = datentyp.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')

            datentyp_list = list()
            for datentypOption in datentyp_options:
                text_datentyp = datentypOption.text
                datentyp_list.append(text_datentyp)

            # Download each element on Datentyp button options 
            for datentyp_list_element in datentyp_list:

                time.sleep(1)
                select_datentyp = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('form-type'))   
                select_datentyp.select_by_visible_text(datentyp_list_element)

                legend_buttons = '  Selecting ' + unb_list_element + ' and ' + datentyp_list_element + '...'
                print legend_buttons
                # Click to download the data
                time.sleep(1)
                browser.find_element_by_id('submit-button').click()
```